# How can I output NSData containing a .gif file from a UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

I have been trying to convert an image to a .gif file contained in an NSData instance, but  iOS provides only 2 methods for image format output:

- `UIImagePNGRepresentation`
- `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`

returning PNG files and JPEG files respectively as `NSData`. Is there any API or way to get `NSData` for .gif files?

I do not have a path or a URL for a file. It is a UIImage which I get after a call to my app's core. Soo, the below code will not work for my scenario.

```
NSString *pathForGif = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"gifFile" ofType: @"gif"];
NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathForGif];
NSLog(@"Data: %@", gifData);
```

Is there any way to output a .gif file from a UIImage?

Comment: you searched a lot, but you missed the first google result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438889/converting-gif-images-to-nsdata

Comment: @GabrielePetronella He wants to take an existing image and convert to GIF data, not read an existing GIF's data.

Comment: @MikeWell "*Is there any API or way to get NSData for .gif files*". Am I missing something?

Comment: He wants an equivalent to `UIImagePNGRepresentation` but which returns the image encoded as a GIF file.

Comment: oh I see. I got it wrong, then. Apologies.

Comment: Where's the .gif file?

Comment: Its a UIImage which I get from my app's call to the core. Its complicated!!!

Comment: Summarize that in your question. It can be useful

Comment: see this link i think you got it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343278/iphone-nsdata-and-byte-conversation-issue