# Uploading GIFs without using UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, animated-gif

I'm having a very hard time trying to upload a GIF image on a WebService. I'm using iOS7.1 as Base platform.

I'm reading the **UIImage** from **ALAssetsLibrary** (The GIF it's on my Photo Library), The URL of the Assets points that it is a GIF Image. BUT, Whenever I want to upload it, I need to use either **UIImageJPEGRepresentation** or **UIImagePNGRepresentation**, and that makes the GIF become a simple JPG or PNG.

I tried reading the Asset URL using the following:

```
NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFilePath];
```

But the NSData always returns in nil. I've struggling with this for hours, and there seems there's no solution for this :S Anyone has ever achieved this?

Comment: Please read 'Converting GIF to NSData' : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438889/converting-gif-images-to-nsdata

Comment: How do u solved this problem? I m also facing the same issue.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
NSData *gifData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[gifURL path]];
```